# http head request slows down script (python requests)

Tags: python, http-headers, python-requests

I'm working on a python script that iterates on a list of urls containing .mp3 files; the aim is to extract the content-length from each url through a head request, using the requests library.
However, I noticed that the head requests slow down significantly the script; isolating the piece of code involved, I get a time of execution of 1.5 minutes (200 urls/requests):

```
import requests
import time

print("start\n\n")

t1 = time.time()

for n in range(200):
    response = requests.head("url.mp3")
    print(response,"\n")

t2 = time.time()

print("\n\nend\n\n")
print("time: ",t2-t1,"s")
```

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is the time it takes to execute. I'm developing an application that already exists, it has almost the same workings (I can read its source, and I'm taking inspiration), but it takes some seconds to do the same thing.

Comment: You probably want to use some form of parallelism (multi-threading/multiprocessing) to make multiple network requests at the same time, or use a form on non-blocking IO (e.g. using gevent or something similar).

Comment: @TomDalton, you're right. Looking carefully to the source of the program I'm trying to reproduce, I discovered that it actually uses multithreading. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A good solution for you could be [grequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests)

```
import grequests

requests = (grequests.get('http://127.0.0.1/%i.mp3' % i) for u in range(200))

for code grequests.map(rs):
    print 'Status code %i' % code.status_code
```